RWC is around the corner, will you be there and want to be greeted?
As I'm sure you're all aware by now, Real World Crypto 2018 (RWC'18) is around the corner, starting on the 10th of January.
Now I know many of us will be there, so I'm posting this question, for anybody who wants to be recognized / greeted to answer with identification markers (in case you don't use just your name here).
If you want to be greeted / recognized at RWC, please answer this question and describe how you can be recognized!

I will be there!
Can recognize me by my name :)

I will be there!
I may find me:

possibly wearing a Crypto.SE shirt
or with a Radboud University tag

(2) will either be me (~10% chance) or one of my colleagues.

I will be there! I can be found hanging out with @Biv.

I will be there!
For starters you can recognize me by:

The Crypto.SE shirt I will be wearing
My name sign having the initials "J P M"
My avatar being on a physical button I will wear along with a Crypto.SE button (If you run into me you'll get one  too, I got a bunch)

More markers will be added shortly before the conference starts!

I was there.
You could recognize me because I was hanging with fellow Crypto.SE people.

I can confirm this claim.
